# iOS 11 and Objective-C warning imported in SWIFT 4.0

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9.1

[image]
[image]

Application had no issues before update to SWIFT 4.0 through Bridging-Header.h
Now I have an error in the imported file of Objective-C through: SWIFT 4.0; xCode 9.1.

The only reason i'm asking here similar question as most people do - all other answers are about SWIFT. This error is in OBJECTIVE-C file. It is not critical, program runs great, but how to fix the error (not to hide).

```
#pragma mark Containment view controller deployment and transition

// Containment Deploy method. Returns a block to be invoked at the
// animation completion, or right after return in case of non-animated deployment.
- (void (^)(void))_deployForViewController:(UIViewController*)controller inView:(UIView*)view
{
    if ( !controller || !view )
        return ^(void){};

    CGRect frame = view.bounds;

    UIView *controllerView = controller.view;
    controllerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    controllerView.frame = frame;

    if ( [controllerView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]] )
    {
        BOOL adjust = controller.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets;

        if ( adjust )
        {
            [(id)controllerView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(statusBarAdjustment(_contentView), 0, 0, 0)];
        }
    }

    [view addSubview:controllerView];

    void (^completionBlock)(void) = ^(void)
    {
        // nothing to do on completion at this stage
    };

    return completionBlock;
}
```

Comment: Restarting xCode - doesn't help. I don't understand why it formats this by SWIFT rules. Maybe the problem is in recognition? Maybe i should somehow mark this as an Objective file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to with Swift.

As the error message states, the UIViewController property `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` has been deprecated in iOS 11. Use UIScrollView's `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` instead